# jQuery loop

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of Divs with class='CCC'. I want to take all these divs in an array using jQuery and then loop through the array. How to do so.

Comment: The documentation of jQuery is really great and not that hard to understand. 

http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// get an array of the divs (will act like one anyway)
var divs = $('div.CCC');

// do something for each div
divs.each(function() {
   // this refers to the current div as we loop through       
   doSomethingWith(this);
});

// or call your method on the array
LoopThroughDivs(divs);
```

Alternatively, these could be written as a single statement (if you only want to do one of them):

```
$('div.CCC').each(function() {
   // this refers to the current div as we loop through       
   doSomethingWith(this);
});

LoopThroughDivs($('div.CCC'));
```

Comment: Any idea how to reverse loop using your code..like pick the last div.ccc first ?

Comment: $('div.CCC').reverse() I think

Comment: Appears it's not in the core but there's many plugins that do it like http://lab.arc90.com/2008/05/jquery_reverse_order_plugin.php

Comment: Thanks..Is there any other way other than using one more plugin?

Comment: Moreover how do you propose using this plugin..like this $('div.CCC')reverseOrder.each(function() ...?

Comment: That line instead of looping reverse, actually rotates the div's physcially..any other suggestion?

Answer (score 7):

With the Each() function:

```
$(".CCC").each(function(i){
   alert(this.id + " is the " + i + "th div with this class");
 });
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Each

**edit:**

as requested:

```
function LoopTroughDivs(selector){
  $(selector).each(function(i){
   alert(this.id + " is the " + i + "th div with this class");
 });
}
```

Comment: As I said, I first want to take it in an array. I will thenbe passing that array to a function called LoopThroughDivss like this:

Loopthroughdivss(divsarray);

Please tell me solution for that

Comment: well that wasn't so clear in your question.. my solution can easily be used in a function that gets passed a parameter with the jquery selector. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this:

```
LoopThroughDivs($('.CCC'));
```

Seriously, that's all there is. You can use the jQuery list as an array.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to put it in an array:

```
 var divArray = new Array();
 $('.CCC').each( function() { divArray.push(this); }); //add each div to array
 //loop over array
 for(i=0, x=divArray.length, i<x, i++){
  //divArray[i] refers to dom object, so you need to use a jquery wrapper
  //for the jquery functions: 
  $(divArray[i]).animate('height', '100px').html("I'm div the "+i+'th div');
 }
```

Note however that the jQuery object itself is an array so you could also do:

```
 for(i=0, x=$('.CCC').length, i<x, i++){
  $('.CCC')[i].animate('height', '100px').html("I'm div the "+i+'th div');
 }
```

Comment: why using a 200 ft truck to carry a ball?

Answer (score -1):

Loop each element and put it into your Array.

```
var yourArray = new Array();
$(".CCC").each(function(index, element){
    yourArray[i]=element;
 });

Loopthroughdivss(yourArray);
```